# Autosar synchronization mechanism from SWC

Tags: autosar

Autosar OS provides `GetRessource/ReleaseResource` API inside a task to protect critical area.

Can software components use directly  `GetRessource/ReleaseResource` for the mutual exclusion? Or is the job of the RTE to generate `GetResource/ReleaseResource` for data that are configured as ATOMIC in the arxml file?

Comment: BTW., what do you actually mean with _for data that are configured as ATOMIC in the arxml file_?

Answer (score 1):

No, these APIs are not available to software-components. The `GetResource`/`ReleaseResource` are indeed used by the RTE as a possible means to implement higher-level semantics, like `ExclusiveArea`, by which software-components can express mutual exclusion.

Comment: is it a configuration in which it's specified if a variable or a whole runnable should run in atomically ?

Comment: Sorry, I don‘t understand the question. What are you talking about: „is it a configuration in which it is specified“. What do you mean by „it“?

Comment: I mean, how to specify that  a runnable or a data structure should be put inside mutex?

Comment: Check the AUTOSAR TPS SoftwareComponentTemplate chapter 7.4 (ExclusiveAreas and InterRunnableVariables). It also describes attributes of RunnableEntity like canEnterExclusiveArea or runInsideExclusiveArea.

Comment: @UweHonekamp according to Autosar spec, a runnable can explicitly enter the exclusive area by calling Rte Enter API call